# Mixing question about sidechain compression in the low range with the bass and the kick frequency

Tags: drums, bass-guitar, mixing

I have a mixing question.  So I have a kick that's got a pretty good sub frequency, but I also have a bass line that does too.  I'm struggling to have both parts hit the way i want.  I've been studying and seen engineers suggest eqing one of them.  On the other hand, I have seen some suggest sidechaining.  My question is does sidechaining a bass to a kick in the sub-range make eqing the bass in that area irrelevant?

Comment: Eq is never really irrelevant.  Maybe you mean something like "does sidechaining mean that you wouldn't make (certain eq decision)?  That seems opinion based though (and the answer might change from track to track).

Comment: This depends on the arrangement. If they both occupy the same temporal as well as frequency space… either change the arrangement or the EQ ;) They don't need to occupy the same space at the same time. If the bass has something to say when the kick isn't doubling it, then a side-chain may help… or it might ruin it. Can't tell without hearing it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends entirely on the frequencies present in both kick and bass.

It's most usual to have a low kick and to high-pass filter the bass above this - you actually won't notice the lack of fundamental frequencies on the bass in the mix - it will bother you if you solo the track, but the audience will never hear it that way.

Sidechain compression is best used where you don't require it to sound natural - e.g. EDM with the obvious pumping of the bass. It is tricky to get it to sound natural and not damage the envelope of the bass. Used subtly it could potentially allow you to keep a little more low end in the bass.

Answer (score 1):

Bro this answer depends that what type of bass are you using
If you are using a bass guitar then , according to me , what you should is sacrifice something
Better you cut off a little amount of frequencies on your bass below 80hz
Now , what you can do is sidechain only sub part of your bass guitar , this will retain the boominess of kick
Now , one thing ( if it suits your production ) you can do is that make sure that kick is small ( probably 1/8 of a bar )
And one more thing , that if kick is too boomy then , make sure you fix that by using the envelope
Hope that helps !